# How to handle multiple request to write a file in php?

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php
    if (!file_exists($folderAddress . $_GET['name'] . '.json')) {
            //create file
            $myJson = fopen($folder.$_GET['name']. ".json", "w");        
            //get a context of a url 
            $ch = curl_init($myUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $text = '';
            if( ($text = curl_exec($ch) ) === false)
            {
                die('fail');
            }
            // Close handle
            curl_close($ch); 
            //copy to json file
            $result = fwrite($myJson, $text);
            fclose($myJson);
            $t = time();
           //add update date to db
            if (!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO test (name )
            VALUES ('$_GET['name]', '$t')")
            ) {
            echo $text;
            mysqli_close($con);
                die('');
            }
            //show the json file
            echo $text;
        } 
?>
```

And i have this problem if users request this file in same time or with less than a 500 ms delay all of them think that the file does not exist. So how can i prevent users to write file when the first is writing on it  ?

Comment: Maybe you could use flock() ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: use SQlite! http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php SQlite is replacement of fopen!

Comment: @dlyaza i don't want to use SQlite is there any other way?

Comment: @MarcelColomb can you change my code with flock please?

Comment: Although it's not relevant to your direct question, please make sure you validate the input of `_GET`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use exclusive lock when writing to a file, so the other processes can't interfere until initial one is complete. You also don't need `fopen` / `fwrite` whatsoever. 
Fetch your data using cURL and use the following snippet:

```
file_put_contents($filename, $contents, LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: So what happen if the `$filename` is locked and user wants to put contents to that?

Comment: Until the process which acquired the lock doesn't release the lock, every other process wanting to write will wait. In other words, they'll "hang" until lock is released.

Comment: I need when some one is writing on this file all other users don't write on this file anymore. for example i the file is open all other users get `die('fail');`

Comment: You can't. And the whole operation of writing to a file will be quick. Unless you have tens of thousands of users waiting to write to a same file at the same time, you shouldn't worry about displaying `die('fail');` and it appears you don't.

Comment: You mean if i have 10,000 users and at a same time all of them request then they will give `die()`?